# forEach Looping of JSON.stringify data from API using ejs

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, ejs

This is a node.js app using express and ejs to call data using an API and then showing that data on the page using JSON.stringify. I am trying to show all of an API data call via a forEach loop on an ejs page. I can make the data show up singularly, but I cannot make it show up as many via forEach looping.

Here's what works, I have the following api set up in my server.js file:

**server.js**

```
//API v4/user/beers/username
const untappdAPI = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.untappd.com/v4/user/beers/username',
  qs: 
   { access_token: 'abc123',
     }    
  };

//untappd.ejs page 
app.get('/untappd', function(req, res) {
  try {
    request(untappdAPI, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    res.render('untappd', {info});
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Something went wrong", e)
}
});
```

And I have the following in my untappd.ejs file:

**untappd.ejs**

```
<%= JSON.stringify(info.response.beers.items[0].beer.beer_name);%>
```

when I run this, the output on the page shows the 1 beer name:

`Beer Name`

Here's what doesn't work, now I want to show all of the beer names on this page so I have tried to set up a forEach loop like this:

```
<% untappd.forEach(function(info){ %>
      <%= JSON.stringify(info.response.beers.items[0].beer.beer_name);%>
<% }) %>
```

But when I run this, I get an error saying 'untappd is not defined'. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

**Full JSON**

```
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "response_time": {
            "time": 0.03,
            "measure": "seconds"
        },
        "init_time": {
            "time": 0,
            "measure": "seconds"
        }
    },
    "notifications": {
        "type": "notifications",
        "unread_count": {
            "comments": 0,
            "toasts": 0,
            "friends": 0,
            "messages": 0,
            "venues": 0,
            "veunes": 0,
            "others": 0,
            "news": 5
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "total_count": 680,
        "dates": {
            "first_checkin_date": "Sat, 15 Aug 2015 01:12:58 +0000",
            "start_date": false,
            "end_date": false,
            "tzOffset": "0"
        },
        "is_search": false,
        "sort": false,
        "type_id": false,
        "country_id": false,
        "brewery_id": false,
        "rating_score": false,
        "region_id": false,
        "container_id": false,
        "is_multi_type": false,
        "beers": {
            "count": 2,
            "items": [
                {
                    "first_checkin_id": 806418145,
                    "first_created_at": "Wed, 10 Sep 2020 15:16:51 -0700",
                    "recent_checkin_id": 806418145,
                    "recent_created_at": "Wed, 10 Sep 2020 15:16:51 -0700",
                    "recent_created_at_timezone": "-7",
                    "rating_score": 1.5,
                    "user_auth_rating_score": 1.5,
                    "first_had": "Wed, 10 Sep 2020 15:16:51 -0700",
                    "count": 1,
                    "beer": {
                        "bid": 3419450,
                        "beer_name": "Beer Name",
```

Comment: Show us your JSON please. We don't know what element to loop if we don't see enough info. It seems that you want to loop the `info.response.beers.items` array, not the `info` object, as is not an array. Actually, you are doing `untappd.forEach` and the error is pretty explicit: `untappd` don't exists. What do you it expect to be? I recommend you to learn a bit about arrays and their methods, as it seems that you don't know what you are actually doing but copypasting code around there.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I've added the JSON as requested

Comment: with this  `res.render('untappd', {info});` you render `info` object inside `untappd` ejs file. You can't loop `untappd.forEach(function(info)`. It is a file

Comment: Thanks Dimitris, so what is it I should do instead, or can you please point me to a place where I might learn about this.

Comment: I guess that you don't followed my tips xD

Comment: Thanks guys, I finally figured it out...

`<% info.forEach(function(beerlist){ %>
      <%= JSON.stringify(beerlist.response.beers.items[0].beer.beer_name);%>
<% }) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I needed to pass 'info' with a newly named function, this is the working code...

```
<% info.forEach(function(beerlist){ %> 
    <%= JSON.stringify(beerlist.response.beers.items[0].beer.beer_name);%> 
<% }) %>
```